# SQL - left join with OR operator (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a left join on a MySQL database like this...

```
select  *
from tableA 
left join tableB on (tableA.id=tableB.id1 and tableB.col2='Red')
```

**...which performs OK with >500K rows on tableA and tableB**

However, changing it to this (and assuming indexes are OK)...

```
select  *
from tableA 
left join tableB on 
((tableA.id=tableB.id1 and tableB.col2='Red') OR
 (tableA.id=tableB.id2 and tableB.col2='Blue') )
```

...kills it, in terms of performance.

So why the performance hit? Can I do it another way?

Comment: OR is a killer even if u have index on the joining keys. So u can use UNION first query with first join condition and next with the 2nd joining condition.

Comment: It's `LEFT JOIN tableName`, not `LEFT JOIN ON tableName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

Not really sure what do you need

- can you show some expected result
- can you tell us what you mean by "kills it, in terms of performance" (does it go to 20sec of execution time ?)

I don't believe its more efficient but try it.

```
select 
    *
from
    tableA as a
    left join tableB as b1
        on a.id=b1.id1 
        and b1.col2='Red'
    left join tableB as b2
        on a.id=b2.id2 
        and b2.col2='Blue'
where 
    (b1.id1 is not null or b2.id2 is not null)
    or (b1.id1 is null and b2.id2 is null)
```

You have to manage the result in the `SELECT` with `CASE WHEN`...

You can compare the performance and put indexes on appropriated columns (depends on what you have in full table and query but here it should be `id, id1 and col2`)

Comment: I just proposed something.

Comment: hey Ryx5, I think you've got it! The key to my initial problem was as Abhik Chakraborty suggested in his comment above (thanks Abhik!). My other problem was syntax, which you've fixed Ryx5, thanks mate! All good!

Comment: @Ryx5 [For my own understanding] I'm having trouble understanding why and how you came up with the "where" statement. Could you (or anyone I suppose) explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh didn't notice that ... how about this ... don't have execution so you'll be able to judge better.

```
select *
from tableB, tableA 
where (tableA.id=tableB.id1 and tableB.col2='Red') OR
 (tableA.id=tableB.id2 and tableB.col2='Blue')
```

Comment: Your queries will produce different result actually.

Comment: there's one subtle difficulty in the original SQL which you probably didn't see, but makes a huge difference, and which is causing me grief...notice the 2 different ID columns on tableB - tableB.id1 and tableB.id2
((tableA.id=tableB.id1 and tableB.col2='Red') OR
 (tableA.id=tableB.id2 and tableB.col2='Blue') )

Comment: hmmmm, tried that too Ananth (thanks), but it's a left join I require, but that's an inner join...