# Mysql slow "OR" operator but union or two separate joins seem no option

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, indexing

I have a typical performance problem of the "OR" operator not using any index in mysql:

```
SELECT sms.smsID, sms.phonenumber, sms.text, date, mbr.name, mbr.prename 
FROM sms INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(smsID) as smsID, phonenumber FROM sms 
group by phonenumber) sms2 ON sms.phonenumber = sms2.phonenumber AND 
sms.smsID = sms2.smsID
LEFT JOIN mbr ON mbr.telephone = sms.phonenumber OR mbr.mobilphone = 
sms.phonenumber where sms.smsmodem = 'GSM1'
order by date desc LIMIT 0,50
```

The query should give back the last fifty received SMS but only one per phone number. Then it should left join it with the mbr table to lookup whether the phone number is connected to a persons name in the mbr table. Anyway in the mbr table the phone number could be in the column "telephone" or "mobilephone", so we have to check against both. The OR operator in the where clause makes the query to get over 20 seconds because it does not use the indexes that exist for mbr.telephone and mbr.mobilephone.

Found solutions are either to do a LEFT JOIN construct like this:
[SQL - left join with OR operator (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926885/sql-left-join-with-or-operator-mysql) or a UNION construct like this:
[MySql JOIN query with OR clause very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997692/mysql-join-query-with-or-clause-very-slow)

But both cases I can not use. The left join construct will return four columns instead of only two:

```
SELECT sms.smsID, sms.phonenumber, sms.text, date, mbr.name,    
mbr.prename, mbr2.name, mbr2.prename FROM sms INNER JOIN (SELECT 
MAX(smsID) as smsID, phonenumber FROM sms group by phonenumber) sms2 ON 
sms.phonenumber = sms2.phonenumber AND sms.smsID = sms2.smsID LEFT JOIN 
mbr ON mbr.telephone = sms.phonenumber left join mbr as mbr2 ON 
mbr2.mobilphone = sms.phonenumber where sms.smsmodem = 'GSM1' order by 
date desc LIMIT 0,50
```

The union solution would just return two columns, but will return every received message twice, once with the name of the sender, once without (as one select will find a corresponding row in mbr, the other won't):

```
SELECT sms.smsID, sms.phonenumber, sms.text, date, mbr.name,    
mbr.prename, mbr2.name, mbr2.prename FROM sms INNER JOIN (SELECT 
MAX(smsID) as smsID, phonenumber FROM sms group by phonenumber) sms2 ON 
sms.phonenumber = sms2.phonenumber AND sms.smsID = sms2.smsID LEFT JOIN 
mbr ON mbr.telephone = sms.phonenumber where sms.smsmodem = 'GSM1'
UNION SELECT sms.smsID, sms.phonenumber, sms.text, date, mbr.name,    
mbr.prename, mbr2.name, mbr2.prename FROM sms INNER JOIN (SELECT 
MAX(smsID) as smsID, phonenumber FROM sms group by phonenumber) sms2 ON 
sms.phonenumber = sms2.phonenumber AND sms.smsID = sms2.smsID LEFT JOIN 
mbr ON mbr.mobilephone = sms.phonenumber where sms.smsmodem = 'GSM1'
order by date desc LIMIT 0,50
```

I am somehow wondering that these "OR" operator problems still exist in 2016...

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` inefficiency continues to exist because there is no easy (or hard) solution.  Even a builtin solution will look a lot like the `UNION` workaround.

Let's look at a solution from a different point of view. You seem to have "an array splayed across columns".  It this case it is a simple 2-element array, but it is causing trouble.  I am referring to phone/mobilenumbers.

Consider not having any such numbers in the main table, but instead having another table of Numbers.  It would probably have 3 columns: smsID, number, and number_type (if necessary).  This eliminates the `OR` by doing a single lookup in the Numbers table.

Since the query seems to be a "groupwise max", I'll also point you at my [*blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) on efficient ways to do that.

Comment: Ok thanks. I hoped there is another possibility than remodelling the data structure. The database as well as the php scripts accessing it exist since 1999, at that time it was considered o.k. to have a table of customers with each column representing one contact detail (phone, mobile phone, e-mail, fax). I will look at the groupwise_max solutions. I know that "procedural SQL" as my query with subqueries is, is not best practice but in regards to performance it wasn't a big problem.

Comment: I now solved the problem on the application side by making two queries to the database, rewrite the result arrays' keys to smsID, loop through one of the result arrays with foreach, check whether there is name information available in any of both of the result arrays for this each smsID and construct the result array out of the results of both. Works with minimal execution time. 

Still it hurts my feelings to do it that way. ;-)